# Android OS built in menu fast switcher

Tags: android, menu

So if you do a zoom gesture inside the Android built in menu, this (see link below) feature appears. I tried to search for this in google, but didnt even know what keywords I should type in...

I have a nice viewpager menu in my app with lot of pages. How can I implement a "fast swither thing" like this for my viewpager menu?

Is something for this in Android SDK or I have to code it manually for myself (gesture, animations, fragments,  etc...)?

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/708/screenshot2013032521590.png